# Class not applied to the input element reactjs

Tags: reactjs

currently, want to style an input element when the input element is not empty and the user has entered text. Below is the code snippet. Class is applied when !input_active but when condition is set to (!input_active && !inputEmpty) class does not apply to the input element.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.input_text_ref = React.createRef();
  this.state = {
    input_active: true,
  };
}

focus = () => {
  console.log("focus");
  this.setState({
    input_active: true
  });
};

blur = () => {
  console.log("blur");
  this.setState({
    input_active: false
  });
};
handle_text_input_change = (event) => {
  this.props.onChange(event);
  this.setState({
    text_input_value: event.target.value
  });
  console.log("withinhandle", this.state.text_input_value);
};
render() {

    const {
      value,
      disabled,
      ...rest
    } = this.props;
    const {
      input_active
    } = this.state;
    console.log(input_active);
    let input_element_classes = [''];
    let inputEmpty = value.length == 0;
    console.log("inputempty", inputEmpty);

    const inputCompiled = value.length > 0;

    if (input_active && !inputEmpty) {
      input_element_classes.push('blur');
    }

    return (
      <input {...rest}
          className={input_element_classes.join(' ')}
          type="text"
          ref={this.input_text_ref}
          onChange={this.handle_text_input_change}
          disabled={disabled}
          onBlur={this.blur}
          //onKeyDown={this.shouldBlur}
          onFocus={this.focus}
      />
    );
  }
```

Could someone help me with this? Also, based on input element validation (empty, disabled, the user entering text so on) how can I change the style of the input element. From the code, it's understood that I am using an array of classes (input_element_classes) based on validation I pop the class and push some other class. Is there any other easy way to do this. thanks.

Comment: You didn't put all of your code. For example there is no definition for this function this.handle_text_input_change. Also, for things like you need I would suggest using classnames library. It is very easy to implement logic for adding, removing, toggling css classes

Comment: edited the code

Answer (score 0):

It looks a bit overload. If I got you right, you can write it this way:

```
export class TextInput extends React.PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isActive: props.value.length > 0
    };
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    value: "",
    disabled: false
  };

  onFocus = () => {
    this.setState({ isActive: true });
  };

  onBlur = ({ target }) => {
    this.setState({ isActive: target.value.length > 0 });
  };

  render() {
    const { disabled, ...rest } = this.props;
    const { isActive } = this.state;
    return (
      <input
        {...rest}
        className={`text-input ${isActive ? "active" : ""}`}
        type="text"
        disabled={disabled}
        onBlur={this.onBlur}
        onFocus={this.onFocus}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

You can find the example in the sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/zl9mmvmp33